# Label name is not rendered unless I specify it explictly in form type class

Tags: symfony

I have this code to render the value and label of fields in a form:

```
       {% for field in filter %}
                 {{ field.vars.data }}
                 {{ field.vars.label }}
       {% endfor %}
```

but it is not rendering the name of the labels unless I set them this way:

```
->add('name', 'autocomplete_q', array('label' => 'A_LABEL_NAME', 'required' => false,'class' => 'ExchangeAdminBundle:Compound'))
```

so is there any way render just the label name without setting it explictly?

Comment: try `with ->add('name', 'autocomplete_q', 'attr' => array('label' => 'A_LABEL_NAME', 'required' => false,'class' => 'ExchangeAdminBundle:Compound')))`

Comment: @Matteo but in that way I'm specifying explicitly the label name also..

Comment: Does `{{ form_label(field) }}` give you nothing?

Comment: @qooplmao `{{ form_label(field) }}` renders the hole label tag, but I want to get just the text inside.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you can add this kind of information:

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Your Name', {'label_attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
```